# How to set env var to AWS EMR master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-emr

I want to set env value to Master node.
for example, I want to have `export AWS_ENV="poc"`. is there any way to use `configuration.json` instead of having one line code in `bootstrapaction`

I tried to use yarn-env.export, spark-env.export but neither of them works for my requirements

```
[
    {
      "Classification": "spark-env",
      "Configurations": [
        {
          "Classification": "export",
          "Properties": {
            "AWS_ENV": "poc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a working emr configuration. Keep in mind that this only sets the environment variables on the master node, not the executors.

```
{"classification":"spark-env", 
 "properties":{},
 "configurations":
  [
   {"classification":"export", 
    "properties":
     {"PYSPARK_PYTHON":"/opt/spark/venv/bin/python",
      "ENV_1":"val_1",
      "ENV_2":"val_2"
     },
    "configurations":[]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

The only difference I can see is a missing configurations key in `classification:export`. Give the below a try.

```
[
 {
  "Classification": "spark-env",
  "Configurations":
   [
    {"Classification": "export",
     "Properties":
      {"AWS_ENV": "poc"
      },
     "Configurations:[]
    }
   ]
 }
]
```